# Get view is called multiple times

Tags: android, listview, getview

Following is my Adapter method,

```
     public class StatusAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private View view;
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<ShipmentMasterDao> listForView;

    public StatusAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList list) {
        super();
        mContext = mContext;
        listForView = list;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listForView.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listForView.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    //Viewholder class to contain inflated xml views
    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mstatus, mDate;
        private ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null || mViewHolder != null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_progress, null);
            //ViewHolder object to contain myadapter.xml elements
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressIcon);
            mViewHolder.mDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
            view.setTag(mViewHolder);

        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }
        ShipmentMasterDao item = (ShipmentMasterDao) listForView.get(position);

        mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(item.getStatus());
        mViewHolder.mDate.setText(item.get_date());
        mViewHolder.mDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return view;
    }
}
```

within onViewCreated method, Im setting the adapter as follows,

```
adapter = new StatusAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), masterItems);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is that getView is called multiple times.How can I resolve this? Is there anyways like I can reset my ui before adding new elements? because since getView is invoked multiple times, the ui is updated with same values the ,multiple times

Comment: Please, paste your complete adapter, the problem is not on getView() method, and the getView() iteration count is based on the get items count.

Comment: i have posted the updated code

Comment: getView is called as many times as it needs, what is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your code:

```
@Override 
public int getCount() { 
    return listForView.size();
}
```

The getView() iteration is based on your list size.
If you want iterate just one time, set a static integer.

```
@Override 
public int getCount() { 
    return 1; // Just one getView() iteration
}
```

BUT THIS IS NOT A BEST PRACTICE FOR ADAPTERS

The getView () method is not a parent iteration.
This is THE ITEMS from your list, with it you create views for each items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

get view is called for each item of list, you no need to solve this, to optimize list view you can try ViewHolder pattern [(example)](https://www.ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/)